# Are there any staged combustion cycle rocket engines under 1000 kN? Is it easier to produce larger engines with this type of engine cycle?

Tags: propulsion, engines, engine-design

I found that most engines developed with staged combustion cycles are inherently quite powerful. Are there any engines which was developed with the staged combustion cycle with a thrust under 1 MN. Also, are there design tradeoffs for smaller engines to avoid staged combustion engine cycle?

Comment: It's probably economics. It's not worth investing all the time and money to develop such a complicated engine for such a small thrust.

Comment: If you see Ursa major company. they're developing staged combustion engines for lower thrusts. Also upper stages had low thrust, but high Isp, and SC cycle was quite good at improving performance.

Comment: It will be interesting to see if they succeed.